# How to customize CMS?

Tags: silverstripe

I have created simple dataobject:

```
class Documents extends DataObject {
     private static $db = array(
       'DocType' => 'Text',
       'ApprovalDate' => 'Date',
       'PublicationDate' => 'Date',
       'DocNumber' => 'Text',
       'DocTitle' => 'Text'

);

private static $has_one = array(
      'Member' => 'Member'
);
```

Give me please any idea how to customize my ModelAdmin so, that all users could only view all objects, and only owner (user with ID == MemberID) could edit and delete his objects?
As the result I want to see such picture:[https://yadi.sk/i/o5Nys_szqnPtQ 
]

I try to use such code:

```
if (!(Member::currentUserID() ==  $Value_of_MemberID_Field   )) {
    $gridfieldConfig->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldDeleteAction')
        ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldEditButton');
    // add a view button
    $gridfieldConfig
            ->addComponent(new GridFieldViewButton());
}
```

How can I get $Value_of_MemberID_Field in the row of GridField?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably look into model permissions: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/permissions/.

For your example, it might look something like this:

```
public function canEdit($member = null) {
    return (Member::currentUserID() == $this->MemberID);
}

public function canDelete($member = null) {
    return (Member::currentUserID() == $this->MemberID);
}
```

Comment: I find it's useful to fall back to the default handler if your validation fails, which is usually ADMIN can do it. eg: `return (Member::currentUserID() == $this->MemberID) || parent::canDelete($member);`

Comment: Thank you King and Dan! I added strings you advised. Alsow I added strings:     `public function canView($member = null) { return true; }` and      `public function canCreate($member = null) { return true; }` It began working as I wanted. But now users can not create new Document : [Yandex](https://yadi.sk/i/bBbnYwa3qtxVy) When I push create button a pop-up window "Forbidden" appear

Comment: The problem is solved in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616176/silverstripe-model-level-permissions-cancreate-doesnt-work/36621037#36621037)